# php call_user_func_array() warning

Tags: php

I am using following code in my program.

```
class A {
function __call($fname,$arguments)
{
    $methods = array('get', 'set');
    foreach ($methods as $method) {
        if(strstr($fname,$method))
        {
            $fname = str_replace($method, "", $fname);
            $function = $method."method";
            if($method == "set")
            {
                call_user_func_array("setmethod", array($fname,$arguments[0])); 
            }
            if($method == "get")
            {
                call_user_func_array("getmethod", $fname);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

function setmethod ($key,$value)
{
    $this->$key = $value;
}

function getmethod($key)
{
    return $this->$key;
}
}
```

and I am getting warrning like this

"Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'setmethod' not found or invalid function name"

and the program get stopped nothing is displayed further.

Comment: So, i take it this is part of a class?

Comment: `call_user_func_array` does not magically recognise that you're in a class context. Use `array($this, "setmethod")` instead of just `"setmethod"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call the global function, while what you need to call the the object member method.

Use an array to present the callback:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, "setmethod"), array($fname,$arguments[0]));
```

Same as:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, "getmethod"), $fname);
```

Comment: what if I use call_user_func() mehtod

Comment: @user2293790 It's the same.

Comment: it is giving me Warning: Missing argument 2 for extenddata::setmethod() and Notice: Undefined variable: value if I am using call_user_func()

Comment: @user2293790 The difference of `call_user_func_array` and `call_user_func` is the way of pass parameters.